# Long inference time when using a pretrained model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I train an LSTM model and save this model. Later i want to use this model only for inference but i noticed there is a significant difference in time. Inference time is longer when using the pretrained model. It is the same script, so i am using the same input, hardware etc

```
trainX, testX, trainY, testY= train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)
model=LSTM(0.001)
model.build(list(trainX.shape[1:]), 1)
mod_file='models/results/lstm/'
#train and save the trained model in mod_file directory
model.train(trainX, trainY, testX, testY, 30,mod_file)

    #predict and infere
t1=time.time()
testPredict = model.model.predict(testX)
t2=time.time()
print(t2-t1)
pretrained_model=keras.models.load_model('models/results/lstm/your_keras_model.h5',compile=False)
t1 = time.time()
loss_dop = pretrained_model.predict(test)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

results:
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
0.04600977897644043
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 645ms/step
0.6814484596252441

How to save the model or what to do in order to have the same inference time?